# How to set HTTP only cookie in NestJS

Tags: typescript, express, cookies, jwt, nestjs

I am trying to implement JWT authorization with accessToken and refreshToken. Both the accessToken and refresh token need to be set in HTTP only cookie.

I tried this code but it is not setting cookies. I am using NestJS framework here.

```
import { Controller, Request, Post, Body, Response } from '@nestjs/common';
@Controller()
export class UserController {
  constructor() {}

  @Post('users/login')
  async login(
    @Request() req,
    @Body() credentials: { username: string; password: string },
    @Response() res,
  ) {
    try {
      // Login with username and password
      const accessToken = 'something';
      const refreshToken = 'something';
      const user = { username: credentials.username };

      res.cookie('accessToken', accessToken, {
        expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 30 * 1000),
        sameSite: 'strict',
        httpOnly: true,
      });
      return res.send(user);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

The res.send() method is working fine i am getting data in response .How can i set cookie here ?

This is my main.ts file: -

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthenticatedSocketIoAdapter } from './chat/authchat.adapter';
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new AuthenticatedSocketIoAdapter(app));
  await app.listen(3000);
  Logger.log('User microservice running');
}
bootstrap();
```

And to get the cookie I am using:-

```
request.cookies
```

Comment: How are you checking for the cookie? That code looks fine to me

Comment: I am using cookie parser and then trying to get cookies with this: - request.cookies

Comment: Are you setting the domain for the cookie? It looks like you aren't so it's probably defaulting to that route and only that route. How are you trying to check the cookie **on the client/caller side**?

Comment: I am setting domain for cookie and on the client side i don't want to access cookies. Now that i updated my Nest cli and their package this code is working fine, i can see cookie in network tab response but now I am not able to get the cookie in backend on next API calls

Comment: The request.cookies gives me empty object every time.

Comment: How are you sending the request from the client side? It sounds like the server side is doing it's job with setting the cookies, it's now an issue of _sending_ the cookies from the client (browser)

Comment: I am using Axios in react for all the API calls, I am not sending the cookie form the front-end, I am little confused  here do i need to enable flag or pass option to Axios to be able to send cookie ?

Comment: I just want to send whatever cookie the server is setting on client's browser back to the server so that I can use the token which is inside the cookie for Authorization in JwtAuthGuard

Comment: I believe Axios requires you to add `withCredentials` to add cookies to the request. If you can show the client code t would be helpful

Comment: Yes that exactly  what I was forgetting.

Comment: Btw, I'd suggest returning access token and keeping it in memory on frontend while keeping refresh token in cookies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Conversation in the comments:

Axios, on the client side, needs to have `withCredentials` set to `true` to send the cookies back to the server. The server was sending and setting thecookies as expected.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered almost the same issue as you. Axios could not save the cookies.
The Chrome required to set up SameSite: 'none', secure: true.
Still did not work thou. It did saved the cookie using fetch method, but only in browsers running with Chromium... So mozilla did not received it. My axios was:

```
const response = await axios.post(url+'/login', loginState, {withCredentials: true});
```

The backend Nestjs: Main.ts:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.setGlobalPrefix('v1/api');
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.enableCors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: process.env.FRONTEND_URL,
  })
  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

My AuthService Login function (remember about passthrought: true in Res)

```
@Post('login')
async login(
        @Body()body: LoginUserDTO,
        @Res({passthrough: true}) response: Response
    ): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.userService.getOne({where: {"user_email": body.email}});
    if(!user) {
        throw new NotFoundException('User not found')
    }
    if(!await bcrypt.compare(body.password, user.user_password)) {
        throw new BadRequestException('Password incorrect');
    }
    const frontendDomain = this.configService.get<string>('FRONTEND_DOMAIN');
    const jwtToken = await this.jwtService.signAsync({id: user.user_id});
    response.cookie('jwt', jwtToken, {httpOnly: true, domain: frontendDomain,});

    return {'jwt': jwtToken}
}
```

Weirdly enough what solved my issue was to add the domain into the response.cookie.

Also my dev env variables used for CORS and cookie domain:

```
FRONTEND_URL = http://localhost:3333
FRONTEND_DOMAIN = localhost
```

Hope my code can help