# Why Nestjs not setting cookies in my browser?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nestjs, session-cookies

I'm making an API in Nestjs that is consumed by an application in ReactJs. My problem is in the login route, when I use swagger, the cookie is saved in the browser normally but when I do a fetch from the front end, the cookie is not saved even though the response headers have the cookie.

I already tried to use all the sameSite options, I tried to put credentials include in the fetch but nothing works. If I log in to swagger first, then I try to do it in react, react copies the cookie that is saved in swagger.

For example, if in swagger I log in with user 1, and in react with the user 2, react steals the cookie from user 1 and ignores user 2 response cookie.

Code in react:

```
    const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/auth/login`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/json", accept: "*/*" },
      // credentials: "include",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
```

Main.ts:

```
    const corsOptions = {
    origin:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ||
      process.env.MY_NODE_ENV === 'development'
        ? [process.env.PLATFORM_LOCAL_URL, process.env.LANDING_LOCAL_URL]
        : [process.env.PLATFORM_PROD_URL, process.env.LANDING_PROD_URL],
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Accept, Origin',
    preflightContinue: false,
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  };

  app.enableCors(corsOptions);
  app.use(helmet());
  app.use(cookieParser());
```

Login Controller:

```
    @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  @Post('auth/login')
  async login(
    @Body() _: MakeAuthDto,
    @Request() req,
    @Res({ passthrough: true }) res,
  ) {
    const access_token = await this.authService.login(req.user);
    const cookiesOpts = {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      sameSite: 'none',
      path: '/',
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 3,
    };
    res.cookie('jwt', access_token, cookiesOpts);
    return {
      response: {
        user: req.user,
        expire: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 3),
      },
    };
  }
```

Work on swagger:

[image: After call login route]

After make request from ReactJs, the response cookies has the jwt:
[image: response cookies, reactjs]

But the cookie are not stored:

[image: cookie not stored]

Comment: This may help you out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66346501/how-to-set-http-only-cookie-in-nestjs

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to set a cookie with the swagger editor.

See [Note for Swagger UI and Swagger Editor users](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/cookie-authentication/):

> Cookie authentication is currently not supported for "try it out" requests due to browser security restrictions. See this issue for more information. SwaggerHub does not have this limitation.