# I'm getting TypeError: res.cookie is not a function while writing what looks to me to be identical syntax to other people; whats wrong?

Tags: javascript, cookies, nestjs

I am trying to send a cookie in my response object using NestJS and cookie-parser.

My expected result is that a cookie is attached to my response object and sent to the client (or in this case, postman). My actual result is that I get this error:

```
web-api_1                | [Nest] 152  - 02/26/2022, 1:15:52 AM   ERROR [AccountController] res.cookie is not a function
web-api_1                | TypeError: res.cookie is not a function
web-api_1                |     at AccountController.<anonymous> (/app/dist/apps/web-api/webpack:/ourRepo/apps/apis/web-api/src/app/account/account.controller.ts:51:13)
web-api_1                |     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
web-api_1                |     at fulfilled (/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:114:62)
web-api_1                |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Here is my code:

```
// at the top
import { Body, Response, Controller, Patch, Post, Request, UseFilters, UseGuards, Put, Get } from '@nestjs/common';

// later...
 @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
    @Post('account/sign-in')
    async login(@Request() req, @Response() res): Promise<any> {
        console.log(43, req.user.email, req.user.id)
        const jwt = await this.accountClient.signIn({ email: req.user.email, userId: req.user.id });
        const refreshToken = await this.accountClient.generateRefreshToken({email: req.user.email, ipAddress: req.ip})

        const cookieOptions = {
            httpOnly: true,
            expires: new Date(Date.now() + 15*60*1000) 
        }
        res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, cookieOptions);
        console.log(45, jwt)
        return res.send(jwt); 
    }
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Look at [this guy's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66346501/how-to-set-http-only-cookie-in-nestjs) and you can see that it works correctly for him; the OP and a helper discuss his issue and they discover his code works correctly. I've copied the form of his code as best as I can. I don't see the issue here.

edit: main.ts to show that I import cookieParser correctly

```
/**
 * This is not a production server yet!
 * This is only a minimal backend to get started.
 */

import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

import { FastifyAdapter, NestFastifyApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import compression from 'fastify-compress';
import multipart from 'fastify-multipart';
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'; // <----- cookie parser used correctly
import { ClusterService } from '@repo/svc-interfaces';

async function bootstrap() {

    const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(AppModule, new FastifyAdapter({
        maxParamLength: 400
    }));
    app.enableCors();
    app.use(cookieParser()); // <----- cookie parser used correctly
    await app.register(multipart);
    await app.register(compression);

    const port = process.env.PORT || 3333;
    await app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0');
    Logger.log(
        ` Application is running on: http://localhost:${port}`
    );
}

if (environment.production) {
    ClusterService.clusterize(bootstrap);
} else {
    bootstrap();
}
```

Comment: The difference are these lines `import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';` and `app.use(cookieParser());`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was wrong. I realized there's Express NestJS and Fastify NestJS. I figured the code i was copying from that thread was for Express and so I googled, "fastify nestjs send cookie" and got this page:

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/cookies

the solution was to `npm install fastify-cookie` and follow the docs.

I changed to using the `setCookie` method they describe in the docs.

Everything's swell.